# Do we need to install x framework even after I used it in a class library and referred it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I used EasyCaching framework and written a class library (Kind of wrapper). when I refer this class library dll in another application, it is throwing exception EasyCaching.Core Not found. PLease install it. Do we need to install it or I did mistake inconfiguration.

Comment: Dependencies of your dependencies **ARE** your dependencies too :D So yes, install it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to provide the EasyCaching DLLs and perhaps config files the framework needs as well as their dependencies (like Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection and others). You deploy them with your installer.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Is there a way where we have stuffed required framework and dependencies in single class library. So that I need not explicitly install these dependencies again in my consuming application. I publised that Library as nuget package still it's the same.

Comment: As long as you have written `using EasyCaching.Something;` in your code, you need to install all the DLLs. Your customer will not know about Nuget at all.